# Async in Django ListCreateApiView

Tags: django, asynchronous, python-requests

I have a simply ListCreateApiView class in Django, for example:

```
class Test(ListCreateApiView):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

     """ Some code which is creating excel file with openpyxl and send as response """

     return excel_file
```

The problem is, when user send a request to get an excel_file, he must wait for 5-10 minutes till the file will return. User can't go to others urls untill file will not download (I have 10k+ objects in my db)

So, how can I add async here? I want that while the file is being formed, a person can follow other links of the application.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has some troubles with asynchrony, and async calls won't help you in cpu-intensive tasks, you'd better use some distributed task queue like [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/)

It will allow you to handle such heavy tasks (i.e. excel generation) in another thread without interrupting the main django thread. Follow the [guide](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django) for integration with django.

Once installed and configured, create a task and fire it when a user reaches the endpoint:
E.g.:

```
# tasks.py 
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def generate_excel(*args, **kwargs):
    ...


# views.py
from tasks import generate_excel

class Test(ListCreateApiView):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        generate_excel.delay()
        return Response()
```

Comment: What about using gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --workers=4 ?
Should it help me?
If i'm gonna work with Celery, it seems, that I must keep all created files on my server.

Now I just send an excel-file to user with response, like that:

`    response = HttpResponse(content=save_virtual_workbook(wb),
                            content_type='application/ms-excel', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={excel_file_name}'`

Comment: Of course expanding your application up to 4 workers will slightly boost it, but as soon your audience grows simply adding more workers won't be enough . Saving media assets on disk is not that critical, and in this particular case winning in performance is much more preferable rather than in memory, imo

Comment: Thank you so much with your solution! I think it the best, what I found!